# How to get value returned from async Task<string> function(); in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have an async method and I want to get a message from the same method when it gets done.

**Below is the code**

```
 static async Task<string> pizza()
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Processing pizza...");
            }
            return "Pizza is ready";

        }
```

**And I want to get receive this message at calling point**

```
....... code 
Task t=null;
            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    {

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {

                         t=pizza();// asynchronous method  

                        });
                        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
                    }
                    break;
 .... other code
```

Comment: Just use `await`

Comment: any reason why you accepted a wrong answer, when a correct one is available from the beginning?

Comment: @Eqra: You may find my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: @StephenCleary, Yes sir thanks a lot, I have gone this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you need the `Task.Run` part? You can `await` of you are inside an async method:

```
var result = await pizza();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

You can also call result:

```
var result = pizza().Result;
```

Comment: Would it run asynchronously? As I have run multiple articles but I am not getting when to use Task.run or when to use await task.

Comment: @Eqra there is no ambiguity. Task.Run runs something in the background. `await` only *awaits* for the result of an asynchronous operation. Your method already returns a Task

Comment: :( Alright. I try to understand, though I am trying this since days!

Answer (score 5):

You can either

```
var pizza = await pizza();
```

Or

```
var pizza = pizza().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: I have done using something like this 
`Console.WriteLine(await Task.Run(() => pizza()));`

Comment: That looks complicated and isn't neccecary.

Comment: `GetAwaiter` is internal method and shouldn't be called

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
var returnValue = string.Empty;
    {
        returnValue = await Pizza();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
```

It will still behave asynchronously. When await statement is encountered, control will return to main thread and execution will not be paused. After a while when Pizza method has returned executing, state machine will automatically execute the returnValue output

You don't need to use Task.Run just for awaiting. You just need to await the async method. Then later on you can use returnValue wherever you want to.

Comment: No, that's what `await` is for. `.Result` will *block* until the task returns which is a bad idea unless you are absolutely certain that the task has already finished

Comment: But It won't remain asynchronous then. I want to do it Asynchronously.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't say that t.Result needs to be awaited. I meant that t.Result can be used after awaiting the method. In that way awaited method still behaves asynchronously and we get our result when it is finished executing.

Comment: Then you don't need `.Result` at all. Just use what `await` returned. BTW, your code won't compile because `t` is **NOT** a task. It's the result of the Task, ie a string

Comment: @Eqra Check the edited answer. It is more elaborated now. Code will execute asynchronously. That is what async/await do. I just meant that after await, you can access t.result which is asynchronous way of retrieving values from async methods. But definitely you need to await first and then use t.Result.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is a task which is the result of async method.

Comment: No, the return value of the method is a Task<string>. The return value of `await Pizza()` is the string. Why don't you try it?

Comment: Yes also think so. Thanks for clarifying. I updated the answer.

Answer (score -4):

If you await it, it will be executed asynchronously. If you do t.Result it will be executed synchronously.

It really depends on your needs to execute it sync or async.

Here we go with the supposed expert programmers downvote rush.

Try to remove await, put .Result and you will get this:

"This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."

Comment: I want to do it asynchronously but want a final message too when my asynchronous method will complete its processing.

Comment: @Eqra that's what `await` is for

Comment: `.Result` *won't* execute anything synchronously. The task will still run asynchronously. The calling thread though will block until the tast returns

Comment: Indeed, calling `.Result` doesn't change how the task executes at all (unless the task's execution needs to execute more code on the calling thread, of course, causing deadlock). It changes how the code calling `.Result` behaves.